# using scss random function to apply a random background color

Tags: css, sass

I've read multiple articles on this, but I can't make it work where I have a list of colors and I want on refresh for one of the colors to apply as the background image.

```
$red: #fc5545;
$pink: #FCCCD1;
$green: #005E61;
$greenLight: #42BA80;
$yellow: #ffcf6f;
$orange: #F57859;
$orangeLight: #FABD91;
$greyLight: #ebebeb;
$greyDark: #2e2e2e;
$blue: #29A8BF;
$blueLight: #B8E3EB;
$blueDark: #142447;

$colors: $pink, $green, $greenLight, $yellow, $orange, $orangeLight, $blue, $blueLight, $blueDark;
$colorsText: $blueDark, $orangeLight, $blueLight, $red, $blueLight, $red, $blueLight, $blue, $pink;

$key: random( length($colors) );
$nth: nth( $colors, $key );
$nthText: nth( $colorsText, $key );

$random: $nth !default;
$randomText: $nthText !default;

.boxTitle {
    background-color: $random;
    color: $randomText !important;
}
```

Everytime I refresh, the color remains the same.

Comment: a cache issue ?

Comment: sass has its place, but you will most likely need JavaScript to apply a random value loaded upon page refresh.

Answer (score 4):

Random only inserts random values when the Sass is compiled, and not on refresh.  Once the css is compiled, it's a done deal.

From https://blog.codepen.io/2013/08/26/random-function-in-sass/:

> Note that the random number that is generated by random() happens when Sass is compiled. When working in the Editor View, that happens pretty regularly: every time you update the Sass code. But when viewing the page in, for instance, Full Page View, we don't re-compile the Sass for each refresh. That is just displaying the CSS that has already been compiled and cached.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue on this is .scss compiled to .css.

It seems to be better to use javascript here. Like this(includes jQuery code but can be converted to vanilla easily).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.boxTitle').css(
  'background-color','#'+ ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6),
);
});
```

Comment: if it can easily converted to JS, then why not doing it? even if the question has nothing to do with JS by the way

Answer (score 0):

I think you  need to use the brackets when you creating the list:

```
$colors: ($pink, $green, $greenLight, $yellow, $orange, $orangeLight, $blue, $blueLight, $blueDark);
$colorsText: ($blueDark, $orangeLight, $blueLight, $red, $blueLight, $red, $blueLight, $blue, $pink);
```