# Use random gradient from my own Custom list for the Bacckground ( SCSS )

Tags: css, if-statement, random, sass, node-sass

I have my few own combinations of gradient that I want to use in my the website background in different areas.

I want them to **Change** every time the page refreshes.

I have already coded the gradient at different paces with different degree on gradient angle using 2 variables

**$primary-color**

**$secondary-color**

Now, In my `variables.scss` file, I want to get random pair of primary and secondary color to be taken as these variables value.

Gradient Combinations:

1. #ffafbd → #ffc3a0
2. #2193b0 → #6dd5ed
3. #cc2b5e → #753a88

I want user to experience any one of the above gradient as the background of different `<div>` tags ( on which i have applied the gradient code ) every time they refresh or new user enters my website

Comment: You need either client side code (JS; after the page is loaded) or server side code (php, asp.net, etc.; when the page is generated) to give every relevant div a random color class. But imho you need to think about the resulting user experience of this behavior

Comment: Itay, I need pure SCSS. 
I'm able to do it uSing JS, but how to do it with only SCSS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using scss random function to apply a random background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956893/using-scss-random-function-to-apply-a-random-background-color)

Comment: I have already gone through that question. Its not helpful. Can I be assertive on the thought that its possible using PURE SCSS ?

Comment: Is it not helpful because it explains why it is impossible with only SCSS?

Comment: I haven't been able to get to that part whether is working or not cause my code started giving error without even working. 
But, If its not possible with pure SCSS i would rather think other options then to waste my time thinking on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220480/discussion-between-sarthak-kuchhal-and-itay).